# Video recorder app in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, video-recording

I am going to write a **Video Recorder app** in **Windows Phone 8.1 (RT).**

I used the **example** provided in Windows Reference.

```
 public sealed partial class CamcorderMainPage : Page
    {
        StatusBar StatusBarObject = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
        string StatusBarHeader = "Firefly Moments";
        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings _captureInitSettings;
        List<Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation> _deviceList;
        Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingProfile _profile;
        Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture _mediaCapture;
        bool _recording = false;
        bool _previewing = false;
        string NoCameraError = "No camera device is found ";

        public CamcorderMainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += CamcorderMainPage_Loaded;
        }

        void CamcorderMainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            EnumerateCameras();
        }


        private async void EnumerateCameras()
        {
            var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
                Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

            _deviceList = new List<Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation>();

            // Add the devices to deviceList
            if (devices.Count > 0)
            {

                for (var i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
                {
                    _deviceList.Add(devices[i]);
                }

                InitCaptureSettings();
                InitMediaCapture();
               // rootPage.NotifyUser("Initialization complete.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            }
            else
            {
                StatusBarObject.ProgressIndicator.Text = NoCameraError;
                //rootPage.NotifyUser("No camera device is found ", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }


        private void InitCaptureSettings()
        {
            _captureInitSettings = null;
            _captureInitSettings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            _captureInitSettings.AudioDeviceId = "";
            _captureInitSettings.VideoDeviceId = "";
            _captureInitSettings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.AudioAndVideo;
            _captureInitSettings.PhotoCaptureSource = Windows.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;

            if (_deviceList.Count > 0)
                _captureInitSettings.VideoDeviceId = _deviceList[0].Id;
        }

        // Create a profile.
        private void CreateProfile()
        {
            _profile = Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(
            Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingQuality.Qvga);
        }

        // Create and initialze the MediaCapture object.
        public async void InitMediaCapture()
        {
            _mediaCapture = null;
            _mediaCapture = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();

            // Set the MediaCapture to a variable in App.xaml.cs to handle suspension.
            (App.Current as App).MediaCapture = _mediaCapture;

            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(_captureInitSettings);

            CreateProfile();
        }

        // Start the video capture.
        private async void StartMediaCaptureSession()
        {
            var storageFile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
                "cameraCapture.mp4", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

            await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(_profile, storageFile);
            _recording = true;
        }

        // Stop the video capture.
        private async void StopMediaCaptureSession()
        {
            await _mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();
            _recording = false;
            (App.Current as App).IsRecording = false;
        }


        private async void ShowFireFlyStatusBar()
        {
            //this will show the Status Bar  


            Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible);
            StatusBarObject.ProgressIndicator.Text = StatusBarHeader;
            StatusBarObject.ProgressIndicator.ProgressValue = 0;

            StatusBarObject.ForegroundColor = Colors.MintCream;
            StatusBarObject.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 166, 62, 59);
            StatusBarObject.BackgroundOpacity = .6;
            await StatusBarObject.ProgressIndicator.ShowAsync();


        }  

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowFireFlyStatusBar();
        }

        private void Camcorder_StartCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartMediaCaptureSession();
        }

        private void Camcorder_StopCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StopMediaCaptureSession();
        }
    }
```

Its working fine as I am getting the video file from Photos App .

Now how to enable live preview while recording in app? Which control to use for it?

Comment: I added the same code, it is working for the first time. But not at the very next time. Even the camera capture task is not working in my app. Should extra code need to be added with this?

Comment: It is because I did not add _mediaCapture.Dispose() after the completion of the process. Working fine now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [CaptureElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement.aspx). Once you add it to your XAML, connect it to your `MediaCapture` object and start preview like so:

```
PreviewControl.Source = _mediaCapture;
await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Have a look at the [UniversalCameraSample](http://aka.ms/2015builduniversalcamerasample) posted on the Microsoft github page for more information. It targets Windows 10, but most of the patterns should work on 8/8.1 as well.

Comment: CaptureElement is not available in WIndows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application. Is there any alternative?

Comment: A `Canvas` with a `VideoBrush`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh202956%28v=VS.105%29.aspx

Comment: yes, that is also way, but I have achieved that with a rectangle and videoBrush.